# Google Play Services Log In Crash

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

Im having trouble with Google's Play Services Log In.
I have a Samsung S3 and the application runs just fine. I can login, unlock achievementens, post highscores, etc.

But I have been testing on some other devices, like the Samsung Galaxy Ace. For that device, when I try to log in for the first time it prompts me for an account (like it would normally do). After selecting it and proceeding, it says com.google.android.gms has crashed. There is no other option other than closing it forcefully and the application just hangs there waiting until it returns to the main app.

Checking the log cat I found this two errors:

```
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464): Error inserting real_time_support=false turn_based_support=false instance_game_id=1 installed=true platform_type=ANDROID package_name=com.ccs.pg preferred=true piracy_check=false
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1582)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at com.google.android.gms.games.provider.GamesContentProvider.a(SourceFile:1516)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at bbe.b(SourceFile:137)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at bbe.insert(SourceFile:116)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.content.ContentProviderOperation.apply(ContentProviderOperation.java:214)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at bbe.a(SourceFile:337)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at bbe.applyBatch(SourceFile:306)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.applyBatch(ContentProvider.java:229)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:95)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:639)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at cmk.b(SourceFile:108)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at cmk.a(SourceFile:92)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at cmn.a(SourceFile:379)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at cmm.a(SourceFile:1944)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at dfm.a(SourceFile:106)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:336)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
02-07 12:34:22.549: W/dalvikvm(1464): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
```

And This one:

```
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Error occured while inserting real_time_support=false turn_based_support=false instance_game_id=1 installed=true platform_type=ANDROID package_name=com.ccs.pg preferred=true piracy_check=false to uri content://com.google.android.gms.games.background/game_instances/4f8b3b51
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at com.google.android.gms.games.provider.GamesContentProvider.a(SourceFile:1695)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at bbe.b(SourceFile:137)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at bbe.insert(SourceFile:116)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.content.ContentProviderOperation.apply(ContentProviderOperation.java:214)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at bbe.a(SourceFile:337)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at bbe.applyBatch(SourceFile:306)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.applyBatch(ContentProvider.java:229)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:95)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:639)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at cmk.b(SourceFile:108)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at cmk.a(SourceFile:92)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at cmn.a(SourceFile:379)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at cmm.a(SourceFile:1944)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at dfm.a(SourceFile:106)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:336)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

From what I can tell, there is a problem inserting some values using SQLite, but as far as I know I have no control over that process.
Also, im not sure what the value "instance_game_id" is used for.

Has anybody had this problem before, knows how to fix it or has any suggestion?

Here is the whole logcat recorded from the moment I try to sign in (incluiding the enableDebugLog for GameHelper).

```
02-07 12:34:10.369: I/InputReader(162): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
02-07 12:34:10.369: I/InputDispatcher(162): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '408fc9c8 com.ccs.pg/com.ccs.pg.MainActivity (server)'
02-07 12:34:10.469: D/BatteryService(162): update start
02-07 12:34:10.469: D/BatteryService(162): update start
02-07 12:34:10.469: D/BatteryService(162): update start
02-07 12:34:10.479: I/InputReader(162): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
02-07 12:34:10.479: I/InputDispatcher(162): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '408fc9c8 com.ccs.pg/com.ccs.pg.MainActivity (server)'
02-07 12:34:10.889: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: Starting USER-INITIATED sign-in flow.
02-07 12:34:10.889: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returned 0
02-07 12:34:10.889: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: beginUserInitiatedSignIn: continuing pending sign-in flow.
02-07 12:34:10.889: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: State change DISCONNECTED -> CONNECTING
02-07 12:34:10.899: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{4050d4a8: android.os.BinderProxy@4057b408}}
02-07 12:34:10.899: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: Result has resolution. Starting it.
02-07 12:34:10.899: D/PhoneWindow(1453): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.surfaceview.GLSurfaceViewCupcake@40586b40 has no id.
02-07 12:34:10.899: I/ActivityManager(162): Starting: Intent { flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity (has extras) } from pid -1
02-07 12:34:10.939: E/SensorManager(1453): unregisterListener:: all sensors,  listener = com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput$SensorListener@4052e4a8
02-07 12:34:10.939: E/SensorHAL(162): +__poll_activate: handle=0 enabled=0
02-07 12:34:10.949: E/SensorHAL(162): > Accelerometer Write /sys/class/input/input3/enable 0
02-07 12:34:10.949: E/SensorManager(1453): unregisterListener:: all sensors,  listener = com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput$SensorListener@40516fc8
02-07 12:34:10.949: E/SensorHAL(162): +__poll_activate: handle=1 enabled=0
02-07 12:34:10.949: I/AndroidInput(1453): sensor listener tear down
02-07 12:34:10.949: I/AndroidGraphics(1453): paused
02-07 12:34:10.969: I/ActivityManager(162): Start proc com.google.android.gms.ui for activity com.google.android.gms/.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity: pid=1526 uid=10016 gids={3003, 1015, 1006, 1007, 2001}
02-07 12:34:11.109: I/MultiDex(1526): load(/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1.apk, forceReload=false)
02-07 12:34:11.249: I/MultiDex(1526): Need extracted file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-1.apk.classes2.zip
02-07 12:34:11.249: I/MultiDex(1526): No extraction needed for /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-1.apk.classes2.zip of size 1502503
02-07 12:34:11.269: D/GCM(1370): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE
02-07 12:34:11.289: W/dalvikvm(1526): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1383: Landroid/app/Activity;.invalidateOptionsMenu ()V
02-07 12:34:11.319: W/dalvikvm(1526): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2418: Landroid/os/Bundle;.getString (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
02-07 12:34:11.319: W/dalvikvm(1526): VFY: unable to resolve static field 899 (THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) in Landroid/os/AsyncTask;
02-07 12:34:11.319: E/dalvikvm(1526): Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method bea.a
02-07 12:34:11.319: W/dalvikvm(1526): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 325 (Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;) in Lbea;
02-07 12:34:11.459: I/ActivityManager(162): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity: +501ms
02-07 12:34:15.199: E/dalvikvm(1526): Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method asy.b
02-07 12:34:15.199: W/dalvikvm(1526): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 532 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Lasy;
02-07 12:34:15.199: E/dalvikvm(1526): Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method asy.c
02-07 12:34:15.199: W/dalvikvm(1526): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 532 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Lasy;
02-07 12:34:15.199: W/dalvikvm(1526): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1341: Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;.getAccountsByTypeForPackage (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[Landroid/accounts/Account;
02-07 12:34:15.199: E/dalvikvm(1526): Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method asy.d
02-07 12:34:15.199: W/dalvikvm(1526): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 532 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Lasy;
02-07 12:34:15.209: I/ActivityManager(162): Starting: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.common.account.CHOOSE_ACCOUNT flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.account.AccountPickerActivity (has extras) } from pid 1526
02-07 12:34:15.229: I/OrientationDebug(162): [pwm] in updateOrientationListenerLp()
02-07 12:34:15.229: V/OrientationDebug(162): in updateOrientationListenerLp(), Screen status=true, current orientation=-1, SensorEnabled=false
02-07 12:34:15.229: I/OrientationDebug(162): [pwm] needSensorRunningLp(), return false #3
02-07 12:34:15.229: W/ActivityManager(162): Trying to launch com.google.android.gms/.common.account.AccountPickerActivity
02-07 12:34:15.229: I/WindowManager(162): Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=1
02-07 12:34:15.239: I/ActivityManager(162): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=704/2 loc=es_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=18 uiMode=17 seq=22}
02-07 12:34:15.419: I/ActivityManager(162): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.common.account.AccountPickerActivity: +198ms
02-07 12:34:15.459: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: onStop, state = CONNECTING
02-07 12:34:15.469: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: onStop: Killing connections
02-07 12:34:15.469: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: killConnections: killing connections.
02-07 12:34:15.469: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: killConnections: all clients disconnected.
02-07 12:34:15.469: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: State change CONNECTING -> DISCONNECTED
02-07 12:34:16.489: W/PowerManagerService(162): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x0
02-07 12:34:17.609: I/InputReader(162): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
02-07 12:34:17.609: I/InputDispatcher(162): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '409fa2e8 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.common.account.AccountPickerActivity (server)'
02-07 12:34:17.659: I/InputReader(162): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
02-07 12:34:17.659: I/InputDispatcher(162): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '409fa2e8 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.common.account.AccountPickerActivity (server)'
02-07 12:34:18.969: I/InputReader(162): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
02-07 12:34:18.969: I/InputDispatcher(162): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '409fa2e8 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.common.account.AccountPickerActivity (server)'
02-07 12:34:19.049: I/InputReader(162): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
02-07 12:34:19.049: I/InputDispatcher(162): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '409fa2e8 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.common.account.AccountPickerActivity (server)'
02-07 12:34:19.099: I/OrientationDebug(162): [pwm] in updateOrientationListenerLp()
02-07 12:34:19.099: V/OrientationDebug(162): in updateOrientationListenerLp(), Screen status=true, current orientation=0, SensorEnabled=false
02-07 12:34:19.099: I/OrientationDebug(162): [pwm] needSensorRunningLp(), return false #3
02-07 12:34:19.099: I/WindowManager(162): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=1
02-07 12:34:19.119: I/ActivityManager(162): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=704/2 loc=es_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=2 layout=18 uiMode=17 seq=23}
02-07 12:34:19.149: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: onStart, state = DISCONNECTED
02-07 12:34:19.159: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: onStart: Now connecting clients.
02-07 12:34:19.159: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: Starting connections.
02-07 12:34:19.159: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: State change DISCONNECTED -> CONNECTING
02-07 12:34:19.159: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: connectNextClient: requested clients: 1, connected clients: 0
02-07 12:34:19.159: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: Pending clients: 1
02-07 12:34:19.159: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: Connecting GamesClient.
02-07 12:34:19.359: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: onConnectionFailed
02-07 12:34:19.359: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: Connection failure:
02-07 12:34:19.359: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper:    - code: SIGN_IN_REQUIRED(4)
02-07 12:34:19.359: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper:    - resolvable: true
02-07 12:34:19.359: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper:    - details: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{405562f8: android.os.BinderProxy@4057b408}}
02-07 12:34:19.359: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: since user initiated sign-in, resolving problem.
02-07 12:34:19.359: D/GAME(1453): GameHelper: We're already expecting the result of a previous resolution.
02-07 12:34:19.479: I/ActivityManager(162): Start proc com.google.android.gsf.login for service com.google.android.gms/.auth.GetToken: pid=1536 uid=10016 gids={3003, 1015, 1006, 1007, 2001}
02-07 12:34:19.669: I/MultiDex(1536): load(/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1.apk, forceReload=false)
02-07 12:34:19.829: I/MultiDex(1536): Need extracted file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-1.apk.classes2.zip
02-07 12:34:19.829: I/MultiDex(1536): No extraction needed for /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-1.apk.classes2.zip of size 1502503
02-07 12:34:19.849: D/GCM(1370): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE
02-07 12:34:19.879: W/dalvikvm(1536): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1508: Landroid/app/PendingIntent;.getCreatorPackage ()Ljava/lang/String;
02-07 12:34:19.879: W/dalvikvm(1536): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1509: Landroid/app/PendingIntent;.getCreatorUid ()I
02-07 12:34:19.989: E/dalvikvm(1536): Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method asy.b
02-07 12:34:19.989: W/dalvikvm(1536): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 532 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Lasy;
02-07 12:34:19.989: E/dalvikvm(1536): Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method asy.c
02-07 12:34:19.989: W/dalvikvm(1536): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 532 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Lasy;
02-07 12:34:19.989: W/dalvikvm(1536): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1341: Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;.getAccountsByTypeForPackage (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[Landroid/accounts/Account;
02-07 12:34:19.989: E/dalvikvm(1536): Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method asy.d
02-07 12:34:19.989: W/dalvikvm(1536): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 532 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Lasy;
02-07 12:34:20.029: I/NotificationStore(1536): file does not exist: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/notification_data.dat
02-07 12:34:20.479: D/BatteryService(162): update start
02-07 12:34:20.479: D/BatteryService(162): update start
02-07 12:34:20.489: D/BatteryService(162): update start
02-07 12:34:22.399: I/global(1464): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 1189ms.
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464): Error inserting real_time_support=false turn_based_support=false instance_game_id=1 installed=true platform_type=ANDROID package_name=com.ccs.pg preferred=true piracy_check=false
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1582)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at com.google.android.gms.games.provider.GamesContentProvider.a(SourceFile:1516)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at bbe.b(SourceFile:137)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at bbe.insert(SourceFile:116)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.content.ContentProviderOperation.apply(ContentProviderOperation.java:214)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at bbe.a(SourceFile:337)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at bbe.applyBatch(SourceFile:306)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.applyBatch(ContentProvider.java:229)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:95)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:639)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at cmk.b(SourceFile:108)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at cmk.a(SourceFile:92)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at cmn.a(SourceFile:379)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at cmm.a(SourceFile:1944)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at dfm.a(SourceFile:106)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:336)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-07 12:34:22.549: E/Database(1464):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
02-07 12:34:22.549: W/dalvikvm(1464): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/(162): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[SignInIntentService]
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Error occured while inserting real_time_support=false turn_based_support=false instance_game_id=1 installed=true platform_type=ANDROID package_name=com.ccs.pg preferred=true piracy_check=false to uri content://com.google.android.gms.games.background/game_instances/4f8b3b51
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at com.google.android.gms.games.provider.GamesContentProvider.a(SourceFile:1695)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at bbe.b(SourceFile:137)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at bbe.insert(SourceFile:116)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.content.ContentProviderOperation.apply(ContentProviderOperation.java:214)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at bbe.a(SourceFile:337)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at bbe.applyBatch(SourceFile:306)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.applyBatch(ContentProvider.java:229)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:95)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:639)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at cmk.b(SourceFile:108)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at cmk.a(SourceFile:92)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at cmn.a(SourceFile:379)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at cmm.a(SourceFile:1944)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at dfm.a(SourceFile:106)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:336)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-07 12:34:22.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
02-07 12:34:25.049: W/PowerManagerService(162): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x0
02-07 12:34:26.269: D/VoldCmdListener(86): asec list
02-07 12:34:30.499: D/BatteryService(162): update start
02-07 12:34:30.509: D/BatteryService(162): update start
02-07 12:34:30.519: D/BatteryService(162): update start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The "Name of the app" field for the Spanish configuration was empty.

---

Found the problem. The error wasnt on the code itself, it was on the configuration of the developer console account.

When you make use of the Google Play Game Services you need to configure the Linked App Details.
Because my app is available on both Spanish and English I created a configuration for each language. Also, my phone, the S3 has its default language on English, while the other devices I tested it on where on Spanish.

So the problem occurred because I hadn't written anything for the "Name of the app" field for my Spanish configuration. Android marked it as an error (highlighted in red), but because the English version had that field filled, in the end it marked no error and allowed me to continue testing. In the main panel of the Play Game Services (the one with the checks) everything seemed fine when it wasn't with one of the language configurations.

So in the end that's why SQLite had a constraint problem. It probably was trying to insert a null value on one of its columns and the GooglePlayGameServicesLibrary thingy didn't check for null values.